!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file AlegreyaSans-Regular-lf-ot1): Font AlegreyaSans-Regular-lf-ot1 at 600 not found
I just upgraded my ubuntu-system from 23.10 to 24.04. MiKtex 24.4 is installed, I use Texmaker as graphical interface. Font "Alegreya" is installed in /home/user/.miktex/texmfs/install
Compiling the following
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{AlegreyaSans}
\begin{document}
Hallo Welt
\end{document}

Results in

!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file AlegreyaSans-Regular-lf-ot1): Font
AlegreyaSans-Regular-lf-ot1 at 600 not found  ==> Fatal error
occurred, no output PDF file produced!

See the complete log-file here: Test.log
miktex-makemf.log shows the following error:

INFO  miktex-makemf - this process (12160) started by miktex-makepk in directory /tmp/mik17793 with command line: miktex-makemf --miktex-enable-installer --miktex-disable-maintenance --miktex-disable-diagnose --verbose AlegreyaSans-Regular-lf-ot1


FATAL miktex-makemf - The AlegreyaSans-Regular-lf-ot source file could not be found.

I know, there are many issues similiar to this, but I tried all and nothing worked.

Welcome to the TeX.SE. For my humble opinion seem that the AlegreyaSans not is installed correctly or not exist in your distribution. I have tried your code and it works correctly.

Remake the font maps in the miktex console, user mode, menu tasks.

Would you please explain in detail how to do this? Thanks a lot!

Problem solved. Just deinstalled all of LaTex in my system and afterwards installed the newest TexLive Version. Synaptic and Ubuntu-Softwarecenter only offered old versions which don't work in Ubuntu 24.04.

Welcome! Unless you install a dummy package, you'll find the old versions get reinstalled .... I find it hard to believe the older versions don't work in Ubuntu 24.04. And you didn't even have TeX Live installed before - you said it was MikTeX.
